# After installing Magento 2.4.1 on windows machine using XAMPP I'm getting two error messages

Tags: magento2.4.1

Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in F:\xampp\htdocs\mag\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php on line 34

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "match", expecting identifier in F:\xampp\htdocs\mag\vendor\magento\module-elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\Match.php on line 20

I have already install composer 1.10.19 and ElasticSearch 7.10.1 Not getting any error message during installation but when I open localhost in the browser just showing the above error message. Clean and flush command used but nothing is changing.

Comment: it looks like you are running PHP8. Magento does not support yet PHP8

Comment: Yes I'm using lastest version of everything expect downgraded version of composer. So how I can Downlgrade PHP.

Comment: @Marius you are right man. just uninstalled the latest version of xampp and downloaded an older version with PHP 7.4 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know only EleasicSearch v 7.6.x is compatible with Magneto 2.4.x
I might be wrong but please ref. to magento documentation.